# How to find the cause of random network timetous

Tags: linux, networking, centos6

I have Centos 6.5 server that is having some issues with random network timeouts. It happens 3 o 4 times per day ( I couldn't identify a specific minute or hour ).

When it happens, it affects almost all applications in this server but only lasts a few seconds. Example:

1) An application that sends a HTTP request to another application at the **same server** ( but in a different IP ) gets a timeout.

2) An application that connects to a mail server ( hosted in the same network, but in a different server ) also gets a time out.

What should I do in order to find the nature of those timeouts?

I already checked the basics like messages in /var/log/messages but I couldn't find anything that could point to the cause of this problem.

And, since it happens randomly, it's hard to make sure that I will be in a SSH session when it happens.

Comment: Install monitoring and gather some data.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Iain that some monitoring is needed to debug.  Since the symptom occurs between two IP addresses on the same server, the root cause may or may-not be network related.  It is possible that something unusual is happening on the network and causing the NIC to stumble.  It is also possible that the root cause is in the server.

To see if the network is a factor, consider running a packet sniffer on the server.  Since the problem is intermittent, perform ongoing monitoring with the ring buffer option.  Two ways to do this are:

a. Run Wireshark while remaining logged-in at the server console.  Ring buffer option found in Capture ==> Options

b. SSH to the server and use a command-line tool such as 'screen' or 'tmux' to create a session that persists after logoff.  Then within the persistent session, use Tshark with the -b ring buffer flag.

At this point, I suggest not specifying a capture filter.  Instead, capture all packets because the root cause could be anything.  The sniffer will create a set of files containing the captured packets.  The trick will be finding the packets of interest within these capture files.  To assist in the search, ensure the server clock is accurate and then be as precise as possible in noting the time when the symptom is observed.

To analyze the capture files, Wireshark's graphical interface is probably easiest.  Using Tshark with the -r flag and piping results to grep can also work.  Use the time stamp to isolate packets around the time of interest.